# Button not getting enabled upon selection of value from drop down in Selenium

Tags: selenium

There is a "Save" button in my application which is enabled upon selection of a value in a dropdown i.e. "Language".

When using Selenium for this, even after selecting this value, the button is not enabled, and hence the test fails, since Selenium is not able to click on the disabled button.

When this dropdown is manually selected the button is enabled.

For selecting the value from drop down i am using "Select" class.

How can i handle this scenario

Comment: Share your code and URL of page

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML, your code trials and error stack trace (if any).

Answer (score 0):

you can try using javascript executor which will execute to turn button enabled from disabled condition,

```
WebElement btn= driver.findElement(By.SELECTOR("LOCATOR"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')",btn);
```

Comment: IMHO, using JS is not the best way to enable element and this should be the last thing to try... Also why you're passing `'disabled'` argument to `removeAttribute` twice?